# Some weird symbols get displayed : "ï»¿ï»¿" on kendo editor control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, utf-8, kendo-ui, character-encoding, telerik

Some weird symbols get displayed : `"ï»¿ï»¿"`, in the kendo editor control, On selecting `"insert ordered list"` button(in kendo editor toolbar).

This issue occurs only when  we change `cdn` reference(http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js) to a local file reference(~/Scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.all.min.js)
 , which contains the same data.

This is working ->

```
<script charset="UTF-8"  src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

But this is not working ->

```
<script charset="UTF-8" src="~/Scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.all.min.js" ></script>
```

After going through this link: http://www.telerik.com/forums/editor-adding-characters-iuml-raquo-iquest- .
 I made few changes but, it didn't  fix the issue.

Changes :
 1. Changed encoding type of the local file to UTF-8 
 2. Specified charset for local file

```
 <script charset="UTF-8" src="~/Scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.all.min.js" ></script>
```

3. Added meta tag

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Since the data in the local file is same as the CDN reference. I am suspecting the response headers. You can find it below. 
Please let me know if you have any suggestions to fix this issue.

My Server Environment is:-
 ASP.net MVC, C#, IIS 8.0 express

Response headers for kendo CDN js file:-

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Age:2090036
Cache-Control:public
Cache-Control:max-age=315360000
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/x-javascript
Date:Mon, 31 Aug 2015 05:26:00 GMT
Expires:Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 16 Jul 2014 11:39:32 GMT
Proxy-Connection:Keep-Alive
Server:nginx
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Via:1.1 f918bd73555184c9b61c8f42f80c79d1.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:emh9zGudv4PxjIHbO0ZEbGIGJoTIGViqcncMZ6ciuUD1geap_pIdfg==
X-Cache:Hit from cloudfront
```

Response headers for local js file:-

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:1731401
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Thu, 24 Sep 2015 10:01:29 GMT
ETag:"fbc07be8aaf6d01:0"
Last-Modified:Thu, 24 Sep 2015 09:25:09 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Comment: The issue is now resolved after remove the meta tag. "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">"